# PHP: flatten mutidimensional array into a peculiar format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi all,

I have the following array:

```
$aryMembers = array(
  array (
    'ID1',
    'Martin Mars',
    'England'
  ),
  array ( 
    'ID2',
    'Marie Arteau',
    'France'
 )
```

)

What do I have to do to flat it into this?:

```
$aryMembers = array(
'ID1'=> 'Martin Mars (Country: England)'
'ID2'=> 'Marie Arteau (Country: France)'
)
```

I've been trying for hours but I'm afraid I don't have a clue on how to do it :((((

Thanks very much

Comment: That's not an array.  Try posting the actual var_dump() or print_r().

Comment: I made a modification, please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arrayMembers as $member) {
    $newMembers[$member[0]] = $member[1] . 'Country:' . $member[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was so obfuscated!